# Python, using print() and replace() function to interpret code given by string

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, printing, wave

Say I have a code given in a string for example:
str(00012333210-1)

The numbers relate to a certain amplitude on a wave I wish to graph.

I want to transform the code into a printable wave where the numbers are replaced by asterisks such as:

```
 3:     ***
 2:    *   *
 1:   *     *
 0:***       *
-1:           *
-2:
-3:
```

Any useful tools to go about doing this?

So far I have tried to split the string into individual numbers however am struggling with the negatives.

For example:

```
file = "000123332101233321000"
x = [int(i) for i in file]
print(x)
```

I only have a very basic understanding of python so i'm very stuck at the moment.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and provide a [Minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to recognize is that printing in a terminal goes from left to right, then top to bottom.  One line at a time.  Since your data are transposed (each value belongs to a column, not a line), you'll need to buffer your entire data set first, before printing it.  In pseudocode it should be like this:

1. Tokenize string into a list of numbers `L`.
2. Calculate `max(L)`.  Loop from this down to `min(L)`.
3. In each iteration (which is one line of output), loop over `L`, and print an asterisk whenever the value in `L` matches the loop index, and a space otherwise.

The second and third steps are something like this:

```
for y in range(max(L), min(L) - 1, -1):
    for val in L:
        print('*' if val == y else ' ', end='')
    print() # next line
```

For your example:

```
L = [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

It prints:

```
     ***     ***     
    *   *   *   *    
   *     * *     *   
***       *       ***
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to convert the string to a list of integers:

```
y = '00012333210-1'
nums = []

for i in y:
    if i == '-':
        sym = i
        continue
    nums.append(int(sym+i))
    sym = ''
```

I am trying to think of better ways to do this.